# Need jQuery Cookie to start and stop script with a button

Tags: cookies, jquery-cookie

I am trying to setup a control for a script (zurb Joyride) that will allow users to start the tour or stop it with an external button. The tour will span across many pages. It is set to start automatically on all pages, but once the tour is stopped, I don't want it to restart on any page within the site without the user manually restarting it. So I am trying to set up a cookie to handle this with the jQuery Cookie plugin.

I am having two problems:

1. The cookie isn't being set when the stop button is clicked
2. The preRideCallback function isn't destroying (stoppin) the tour

Here is my code:

```
 <a href="#" class="button" id="openTour">START TOUR</a>
  <a href="#" class="button" id="no-tour">STOP TOUR</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
            autoStart : true,
            cookieMonster: false,
            modal:true,
            expose: true
        });


    $('#stopTour').click(function() {   
        $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride("destroy", function(i,origValue){
        cookieMonster: true,          
        cookieName: 'JoyRide', 
        cookieDomain: false 
        });
    });

    $('#openTour').click(function() {
        $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
            autoStart : true,
            cookieMonster: false,
            modal:true,
            expose: true
        });
    });
});
```